# Print prime numbers within an interval

Tags: python, primes

This code is running for the 1-10 interval but for interval 20-30 it is writing 21 and 27 and I am unable to understand what's wrong in the code.  I don't want to know other code; I want to know what's wrong in my code.

```
start = int(input("Enter the first number of the interval")) #starting of interval
end = int(input("Enter the last number of the interval")). #end of interval

for i in range(start, end+1):
    for x in range (2,end):
        if (i == 0 or i==1):
            break
        elif (i % x != 0):
            print(i)    
            break
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Your problem is too much break dancing.

Comment: You need to check for the whole range of possible divisors _before_ deciding to print each number, right now, having any divisor candidate that does not divide the number causes it to be printed as a prime. for example 15, [not divided by two --> it is prime] which is of course false as it's able to be divided by 3 and 5 still.

Comment: Does this really work for the 1-10 interval? Since the inner loop always immediately breaks, it should only check even/odd not prime.

Comment: your code prints 3,5,7,9 on interval 1-10. Your inner for with if-elif-else contiditions are wrong.

Comment: Since you are printing 3,5,7,9 on interval 1-10, your code is wrong. That is why you get printed 21 and 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in range (2,end):
    if (i == 0 or i==1):
        break
    elif (i % x != 0):
        print(i)    
        break
    else:
        break
```

This part of code should

> `print` a number if it's prime, otherwise `break`

but it doesn't.

---

Do you notice something strange in your code? I do, and it's the fact that in every case the inner `for` loop `break`s after the first iteration, rethink this aspect of your code, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure whether you want the period after the inputting for the end. Also, your code checks if `i` is not divisible by `x`, then print. So for example, your code checks if 21 is divisible by 2. It is not, so your code prints it out and breaks.

Answer (score 0):

***Introduction***

---

Your code is effectively testing if a number is odd and if it is, it prints it out.

If `start` is 1 and `end` is any number greater than 1, your code is printing every odd number greater than 2 in the interval `[1, end]`.

It is printing all odd numbers, but not all odd numbers are prime!

---

***Dissecting your code***

---

Let's consider the [1, 20] interval. Your code outputs every odd number greater than 2 in the interval `[1, 20]`.

> 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19.

2 is prime and is missing from this list. We can fix that by writing the following within the outer loop but above the inner loop:

```
if i == 2:
    print(i)
```

Now the output is `

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19.

This is better but `9, 15` are not prime numbers.

The `if` statement with condition `(i == 0 or i == 1)` inside of your inner loop is not causing any problems. Let's simplify the inner loop by moving this just outside of the inner loop (just above) so that your code becomes

```
for i in range(start, end+1):
    if (i == 0 or i == 1):
        # 0 and 1 are not prime
        continue
    if (i == 2):
        # 2 is prime 
        print(i)
    for x in range (2,end):
        if (i % x != 0):
            print(i)
            break
        else:
            break
```

All that remains as the potential culprit for your problems is the inner loop so let's focus on that.

- Whenever `i` is even, in the first iteration of the inner loop, we
  have `x = 2`. We know that if `i` is even that `i % 2` is 0 and so `i % x != 0` is `False` and so we move onto the `else`, in which case we
  break out of the inner `for` loop. This is all fine because no even
  integer greater than 2 is prime!
- Whenever `i` is odd, in the first iteration of the inner loop, we
  have `x = 2`. We know that if `i` is odd that `i % 2` is NOT 0 and so
  `i % x != 0` is `True` and then we print `i` and then `break` out of
  the `for` loop.

We never once have `x = 3` or `x = 4` and so on!

The above describes precisely what you code is doing, which is ignoring even integers and simply printing out every odd integer.

---

***Solution that outputs what you want***

---

It would help me if I knew what definition of a prime number you have and/or what algorithm you are trying to implement. But since I don't have this information, I can only suggest a solution.

In order to solve your problem, you need to clearly have in mind what a prime number is. There are many equivalent definitions of a prime number (see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) prime number page for examples of definitions). I chose a definition that suggests a natural algorithm for finding prime numbers. Whatever definition of prime number you were given, it is possible to prove mathematically that it is equivalent to this (for some this is the first definition of a prime number that they see!):

> An integer i is prime if and only if i > 1 AND for all k in {2, 3,
> ..., i - 1}, i % k != 0.

In words this says that an integer `i` is prime iff `i` is strictly greater than 1 and for all integers `k` from `2` up until `i - 1`, `k` does not divide `i` evenly.

Here it is

```
start = int(input("Enter Start: "))
end = int(input("Enter End: "))

print(f"\nPrime numbers between [{start}, {end}]:")
for i in range(start, end + 1):
    if (i == 0 or i == 1):
        # i is not prime
        continue
    if (i == 2):
        # i is prime
        print(i)
        continue

    for x in range(2, i):
        if (i % x) == 0:
            break

    if (i % x) != 0:
        print(i)
```

Example session:

```
Enter Start: 20
Enter End: 30

Prime numbers between [20, 30]:
23
29
```

The `(i == 0 or i == 1)` check should be placed outside the inner `for` loop. Otherwise, for all `i` greater than or equal to 2, for every iteration in the inner loop, you will be checking to see if it is less than 2 or not. You are doing this check too much.

We know that when `i == 2` that `i` is prime.

For `i > 2`, we appeal to the definition of a prime number above.

The inner loop and the last statement applies the second part of the prime definition.